# Save form as raw HTML into a file django

Tags: python, html, django

I`m trying to save the content of a form as raw html to a file, on server, or into a variable in views.py.

The form contains a editable table.

I added views.py and page.html (the form with the table I want to save)

views.py

```
 @login_required(login_url='/')
 def creareorar(request):

// ......

elif 'save_orar' in request.POST:

    c['test']='form1'
    c.update(csrf(request)) 
    return render_to_response('creareorar.html', c) 

c.update(csrf(request)) 
return render_to_response('creareorar.html',c)
```

page.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table id="{{tabelorar}}" class="tabelorar">
            // content
        </table>
        <input style="left:90%;" type="submit" name="save_orar" value="Save">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your view so that you save the template to a file rather than returning it:

```
def creareorar(request):
    .
    .
    .
    form_html = render_to_response('creareorar.html', c)
    form_file = open('path/to/file.html', 'wb')
    form_file.write(form_html)
```

Comment: I receive "TypeError at /creareorar/

must be convertible to a buffer, not HttpResponse" on line with "form_file.write(form_html)"

Comment: Ok, I transformed form_html to string with str() and saved the html page to file, but without the changes I made in my browser page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. However, this is what you need to do to create the HTML as a file. How you populate the HTML is no different from what you'd normally do.

Comment: In the form is a table which is edited by a "user" using jquery sortable. After he mades the changes and submit, I want to save the table and it`s content in a variable, or in db, or somewhere for late use.

Comment: That's a different question than you're asking here, best to post it as a new question.